# Infected Cylinder and Torus

Tags: mathematics, graph-theory, cellular-automata

A variant of the well known [Infected Checkerboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18074/checkerboard-infection) problem. If we've a x square, then we fold it along top and bottom row to form a cylinder. A cell in this cylinder becomes infected if at least two of its neighbors (orthogonal only) are infected. Prove that, initially, if the number of infected cells is less than , the whole cylinder can't be infected.

Additionally, instead of cylinder, let's form a torus by joining the sides of the square. Prove that -1 initial infected cells are necessary to infect the whole torus.

The square variant can be solved by observing the perimeter of the infected cells.

Comment: Doesn't the same argument still apply? Except now you don't need to cover a perimeter of a n x n square, but of a (n-1) x n rectangle in the case of a cylinder, then of a (n-1) x (n-1) square in the case of a torus.

Comment: A cylinder would still have n x n cells (and same for torus) as we're not merging the top & bottom row but concatenating them with sides.

Comment: Yes, we still have n x n cells but we only need to infect (n-1) x n sub-rectangle or (n-1) x (n-1) sub-square (using the perimeter argument), because then the infection automatically spreads to the remaining cells (because of the folding) and infects the entire cylinder or torus.

Comment: I think you’re right. I complicated things unnecessarily and was thinking why do we necessarily need to have n-1 x n rectangle infected first. But it’s obvious that the rectangle will inevitably be involved as part of infecting the whole cylinder. Thanks! Unfortunately I‘m unable to upvote your comment, so if you can add it as an answer I’ll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: Also asked on math.SE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988288/infection-spread-on-a-torus-chessboard) and MO (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381576/spread-of-a-disease-on-a-modular-chessboard-torus-lower-bound)

Comment: @Vepir there’s a counter sample for your answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3988288/522463 (answer 2) and there’s a correct answer there too (answer 1)

Comment: @user2471 I do not follow how that is a counter example to my comment. If you wlog shift the last picture down by 1 row, we still have perimeter 10 and not 12 (because we are on a torus).

Comment: @Vepir I guess I’m not understanding your reasoning. Some crucial detail seems to be missing. Would you mind writing a detailed answer? In your first comment, it seems that you’re stating that (1) to infect the torus you have to infect a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ sub grid, (2) which requires at least $n-2$ infected cells based on the perimeter argument. (2) is clear, but (1) is not obvious to me.

Comment: @user2471 Doesn't this [(answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3992130/318073) that you linked already work? The "counter sample" that says otherwise looks irrelevant to me, because the torus doesn't really have a "border", so we can simply highlight the grid in a different way: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8jH8.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8jH8.png) and the argument still holds?

Comment: @Vepir my apologies for being slow here. First how do you prove that $n-2$ initially infected cells have to belong to a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ subgrid with clean row above it and clean column right to it ? Say you found one subgrid that fits this property, how do you prove that cells infected outside the grid don’t affect your perimeter? Finding that subgrid does not seem to be sufficient to carry your reasoning forward as shown in the example in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3988288/522463.

Comment: @Vepir I think in https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8jH8.png you need to assert something more than just finding a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ subgrid with one clean row above it and one clean row to its right. There’s an extra padded row and column that make infections from outside not influence your restricted perimeter.

Comment: I think I only now realize what the "counter sample" meant. The selected (n-1) x (n-1) subgrid is "constant" because it is selected before infection spread, which is a problem. My bad. To not duplicate conversations, I will stop commenting here and move any future replies to the [actual answer that we are discussing](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3992130/318073).

Comment: @user2471 As for my initial comment, I agree that it is not completely clear that "the sub grid will inevitably be involved as part of infecting the whole cylinder".